# Como filtro segun el dia y mes?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

Tengo un ejercicio en el cual me pide filtrar todos los pedidos que se realizaron en la temporada de otoño.
Desde el 21 de setiembre al 21 de diciembre.

La tabla comandes:

| num_pedido | data | importe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112993 | 1989-01-04 | 1896.00 |
| 112979 | 1989-10-12 | 15000.00 |
| 112968 | 1989-10-12 | 3978.00 |
| 112992 | 1989-11-04 | 760.00 |
| 112975 | 1989-12-12 | 2100.00 |
| 112963 | 1989-12-17 | 3276.00 |
| 112961 | 1989-12-17 | 31500.00 |
| 112983 | 1989-12-27 | 702.00 |
| 112987 | 1989-12-31 | 27500.00 |
| 112989 | 1990-01-03 | 1458.00 |
| 112997 | 1990-01-08 | 652.00 |
| 113007 | 1990-01-08 | 2925.00 |
| 113012 | 1990-01-11 | 3745.00 |
| 113013 | 1990-01-14 | 652.00 |
| 113024 | 1990-01-20 | 7100.00 |
| 113027 | 1990-01-22 | 4104.00 |
| 113003 | 1990-01-25 | 5625.00 |
| 113034 | 1990-01-29 | 632.00 |
| 110036 | 1990-01-30 | 22500.00 |
| 113042 | 1990-02-02 | 22500.00 |
| 113045 | 1990-02-02 | 45000.00 |
| 113051 | 1990-02-10 | 1420.00 |
| 113048 | 1990-02-10 | 3750.00 |
| 113049 | 1990-02-10 | 776.00 |
| 113055 | 1990-02-15 | 150.00 |
| 113057 | 1990-02-18 | 600.00 |
| 113058 | 1990-02-23 | 1480.00 |
| 113062 | 1990-02-24 | 2430.00 |
| 113065 | 1990-02-27 | 2130.00 |
| 113069 | 1990-03-02 | 31350.00 |

Estaba probando esta sentencia con la funcion date_part:

```
SELECT * FROM comandes 
WHERE date_part('month', data) BETWEEN 09 and 12;
```

Pero no se me ocurre como filtrar entre el rango de dias ...

Alguna idea ?

Gracias.

Comment: y por qué usaste los tags mysql y postgresql, si tienes certeza del entorno en que corres?

Comment: Y porque te enfocas en esos detalles relevantes en vez de ayudar con la pregunta en si? Ya los quite. Saludos

Comment: porque la respuesta es distinta según el motor, Bruno, y yo estoy encantado de ayudar pero necesito que el problema se describa racionalmente, específico. No es por jorobarte ni por ser fariseo.

Answer (score 2):

prueba intentando:

```
 SELECT * FROM comandes WHERE (MONTH(data) >= 9 AND DAY(data) >= 21) AND (MONTH(data) <= 12 AND DAY(data) <= 21)
```